# conditional labeling in rows

Tags: r, algorithm, dplyr

I would like to label rows based on the condition in other rows.

basically, what I look for is if the row is `NA` then look for row with non-NA and use its `sd_value` column to decide to whether label the NA row with its label else label it with NA. I hope this explanation is straightforward.

So lets say we have

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(0.5,1,0.6,1.2), sd_value=c(0.1,0.5,0.2,0.8),
             label = c("good", "bad",NA,NA))


> df
  value sd_value label
1   0.5      0.1  good
2   1.0      0.1   bad
3   0.6      0.5    NA
4   1.2      0.8    NA
```

to label for example row 3, I need to check that row value and then check whether or not they lie in between `'good'` or `'bad'` value±2*sd_value. If so label them `good` or `bad`.

the expected output

```
> df
  value sd_value label
1   0.5      0.1  good
2   1.0      0.1   bad
3   0.6      0.5  good   #because 0.6 is ±2*sd_value of 1st row value 
4   1.2      0.8   bad   #because 1.2 is ±2*sd_value of 2nd row value
```

to generalise the question more lets say we have a data like this

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(0.5, 1,8, 1.2, 2.4,0.4,6,2,5.7, 9),   
                 sd_value=c(0.1, 0.1,1, 0.2,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.1),
                 label = c("good",NA,"beautiful","bad", NA,NA,"ugly","dirty",NA,NA))


> df
   value sd_value     label
1    0.5      0.1      good
2    1.0      0.1      <NA>
3    8.0      1.0 beautiful
4    1.2      0.2       bad
5    2.4      0.2      <NA>
6    0.4      0.1      <NA>
7    6.0      0.4      ugly
8    2.0      0.2     dirty
9    5.7      0.1      <NA>
10   9.0      0.1      <NA>
```

Based on the conditions the expected output should look like

```
> df
   value sd_value     label
1    0.5      0.1      good #original label
2    1.0      0.1      bad
3    8.0      1.0      beautiful #original label
4    1.2      0.2      bad
5    2.4      0.2      dirty
6    0.4      0.1      good
7    6.0      0.4      ugly #original label
8    2.0      0.2      dirty #original label
9    5.7      0.1      ugly 
10   9.0      0.1      beautiful
```

those changed NA rows based on the `±2*sd_value` of non-NA rows value.

Comment: Isn't the 3rd value is checked based on `0.5 + 0.1 * 2` = `0.7`

Comment: Both the first and the second ```NA``` lie in between 2 sd from the first (good) and the second value (bad). How do you assign good or bad? The closest?

Comment: @akrun yes.3rd value (0.6)<= 0.7. So it should be labeled as `good`. before the expected output I tried to emphasize that.

Comment: @c1au61o_HH yes the closest. That's way I defined some `sd_value` to make decision.

Comment: @akrun sorry. fixed that NA issue.

Comment: Also, one more doubt, if you have multiple `good/bad` as in the original data, what would be the criteria to check for NA

Comment: @akrun ow! I found an issue related to c1au61o_HH. So sd_values updated in the original data!. Sorry again!my bad!

Comment: @akrun The criteria is just the row is NA or not. I have the real data good/bad sd_values well defined.

Comment: Isn't this `i1 <- df[-(1:2), ]$value < df$value[1] + 2 * df$sd_value[1]; df$label[3:4] <- c("bad", "good")[(i1+1)]`

Comment: @akrun yes. but prefer to have solution in dplyr and maybe writing some small function ? I could not figured out how:(

Comment: How exactly does this differ from the question you already posted today?

Comment: @camille I little bit extended the OP for generalize the solution way.

Comment: @Alexander  While applying codes on latest dataset, it is matching to different label.  Is that expected outputright?

Comment: yes. I extended the original dataset and mix the rows little bit.

Comment: @akrun brilliant solution with `cut`. Thanks akrun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the `NA` row 'value's and check that with the 'value', 'sd' corresponding to the 'good' 'label, change the logical vector ('i2') to 'good/bad' either with numeric indexing or using `ifelse` and assign the output back to the column based on the index ('i1')

```
i1 <- is.na(df$label)
i2 <- df$value[i1] < abs(df$value[1] + 2 * df$sd_value[1])
df$label[i1] <- c("bad", "good")[(i2 + 1)]
```

---

It can be wrapped in a function

```
f1 <- function(data, lblCol, valCol, sdCol){
     i1 <- is.na(df[[lblCol]])
     gd <- which(df[[lblCol]] == "good")
     i2 <- df[[valCol]][i1] < abs(df[[valCol]][gd] + 2 * df[[sdCol]][gd])
     df[[lblCol]][i1] <- c("bad", "good")[(i2 + 1)]
     df
  }

f1(df, "label", "value", "sd_value")
#  value sd_value label
#1   0.5      0.1  good
#2   1.0      0.5   bad
#3   0.6      0.2  good
#4   1.2      0.8   bad
```

#### Update

With the updated dataset, we extract the rows where the 'label' is non-NA, `arrange` it in ascending order and use that in `cut` to cut the 'value' to get the correct 'label'

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 <- df %>% 
      filter(!is.na(label)) %>% 
      transmute(label, v1 = value + 2 * sd_value) %>%
      arrange(v1)
df %>% 
    mutate(label = cut(value, breaks = c(-Inf, df1$v1), labels = df1$label)) 
#   value sd_value     label
#1    0.5      0.1      good
#2    1.0      0.1       bad
#3    8.0      1.0 beautiful
#4    1.2      0.2       bad
#5    2.4      0.2     dirty
#6    0.4      0.1      good
#7    6.0      0.4      ugly
#8    2.0      0.2     dirty
#9    5.7      0.1      ugly
#10   9.0      0.1 beautiful
```

---

Or the same logic in `base R`

```
df1 <- transform(na.omit(df), v1 = value + 2 * sd_value)[3:4]
df$label <- cut(df$value,  breaks = c(-Inf, df1$v1), labels = df1$label)
```

Comment: I knew it's a complex problem. Do you think Akrun there could be universal way to do it ? Such as find the NA row and look for the non-NA ones and their sd_values than if this NA row value closer to non-NA's value label same as them. That would be great if we have it. Thumbs up!

Comment: @Alexander  In the function, it is more general where it looks for the `good' row, extract the value and then do the comparison.  Of course, it is assumed there is only one good/bad row (which is the reason I commented earlier about that case)

Comment: @Alexander Also, here we are not checking the 'bad' row, as the opposite of 'good' is assumed to be 'bad'

Comment: @Well I have good `bad` `ugly` `dirty` and `beautiful` too :) In that case this function little hold me back right ?

Comment: @Alexander Hmm.  In that case, have to make slight adjustments in the function by adding `bd <- which(df[[lblCol]] == "bad")`  Suppose if "good" condition is false, then where does it naturally fall into?

Comment: their location is actually random in the real data. Ok. I'll update the OP. stay tuned.

Comment: I updated the OP. Please see the end of the question. Cheers!